# What does @Preload do (Jira Active Objects)?

Tags: java, jira

I use Active Objects for persisting data. What exactly does this annotation do?

P.S. I found this description (https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/browse/AO-486):

> We hit the problem several times where AO will load each field of an object by a separate SQL query:
>   https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONFDEV-21100
>   https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONFDEV-21206 
>   It can be bypassed with @Preload annotation on a class but preloading is not a default behaviour. Obviously not preload introduces a big performance hit when client code needs more than one attribute. I would imagine preloading would be a sensible default given that it would cause very little overhead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"**@Preload**" is used to eagerly load all fields for an entity. By default the behavior is to load only the ID field eagerly and lazy load other fields within an entity.

Comment: I can assume the use case for this would be streaming entries via active objects. I faced a bug where only ID field was loading while testing. @Preload would be the tag which might load all entries.